# nodejs http module - image upload

Tags: node.js

I am pretty supcied there is not a stack question about this.
How can i create a nodejs http module file upload?

I have a server, witch will reaceave a file + some form parameters, how can i get the image( i will need to resize the image, then upload to other server later ).

My current code:

```
 17 // Searches Elasticsearch and return's firebase references
 18 http.createServer(function(request, response) {
 19   var method = request.method;
 20   var url = request.url;
 21   var body = [];
 22 
 23   // Fetches body and pushes into array
 24   request.on('error', function(err) {
 25     console.error(err);
 26   }).on('data', function(chunk) {
 27     body.push(chunk);
 28   }).on('end', function() {
 29     body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
 30     response.statusCode = 200;
 31     response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 32 
 33     // Mini router
 34     if(url == "/save_photo") {
 35       upload_photo.resizeAndSavePhoto(request);
 36       response.write("body");
 37       response.end();
 38     } else {
 39       search.searchElasticsearchForMaches(request, url, elasticsearchUrl, elasticsearchPort).then((data) => {
 40         response.write(data);
 41         response.end();
 42       });
 43     }
 44   });
 45 }).listen(8080);



  1 var http = require('http');
  2 
  3 module.exports = {
  4   resizeAndSavePhoto: function(body) {
  5     console.dir(body.files);
  6   }
  7 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `ImageMagick` or `GraphicsMagick` i would prefer `gm` as it is more better in performance and stable for node.Graphic magick should be install on your server

you can install gm like this

```
npm install gm
```

For more details check this
http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html

Comment: But how can i parse the image? Like from the request?

Answer (score 0):

This package solved my problems: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable